# POST command (PHP) refuses to concatenate

Tags: php, html, concatenation

So I'm trying to design a website that will allow the user to input data to design a tower. When it comes to the dimensions of basic parts of the tower (the height, width, and depth), I want to present them in a H x W x D format (i.e. 3 x 2 x 2). Trouble is, I'm having problems with concatenation in the PHP file for the second page of the website where everything's displayed.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Results for tower design</title>
</head>
<body>
    Pillar base shape: <?php echo $_POST["tBase"]; ?><br>
    Pillar dimensions: <?php echo ($_POST["tHeight"];)." x ".($_POST["tWidth"];)." x ".($_POST["tDepth"];) ?><br>
</body>
</html>
```

It's highly possible that I might be making a common beginner error. If so, I want to know where I went wrong and how to avoid it.

Comment: From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated** with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

Comment: ...and running this, would have thrown you `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in...` but you failed to either check for errors or posted that error.

Answer (score 2):

You have some extra semicolons in improper places. A semicolon indicates the end of a PHP statement. You should not use them in the middle of building a string.

```
($_POST["tHeight"];)
```

Remove them and make sure you sanitize your output (or you'll be open to [XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php))

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST["tHeight"])." x ".htmlspecialchars($_POST["tWidth"])." x ".htmlspecialchars($_POST["tDepth"])
```

---

Running this, would have thrown you: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in...`

Use error reporting during testing.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Plus, make sure your POST arrays contain values and that your form uses a post method with matching named attributes.

Comment: and you know what they say about semicolons *eh?* ;-) edit: ah, you did. My bad.

Comment: The ink to manual about that: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good stuff

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. You can rollback if you want ;-)

Comment: OK, everything suggested here only prints out the two X's. (That means everyone's answers, not just yours). I'm still not getting the tHeight, etc. variables printed out. Could I be doing something else wrong?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($_POST);` and make sure that variable is set. Could have a typo in the field name

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact, you can have it all showed as a single line:

```
Pillar dimensions: <?php echo "{$_POST["tHeight"]} x {$_POST["tWidth"]} x {$_POST["tDepth"]}"; ?>
```

Every echo that is wrapped with double quotes can have variable been echoed just wrapping with `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolumns

```
<?php echo ($_POST["tHeight"] ." x ".$_POST["tWidth"] ." x ".$_POST["tDepth"]); ?>
```